# Mint - Copied my tox profile to new client but qtox can't use my chat history

Tags: linux-mint, flatpak

I recently tried to move from the flatpak version of qtox to the native linux version and as instructed on the wiki i copied my profile with all the corresponding files to the ~/.config/tox folder.

When i log in my profile and contacts are correctly recognized, but i get a message saying that

```
qTox couldn't open your chat logs, they will be disabled.
```

and when i check the folder my .db file has been moved to a .db.bak and an new empty .db has been created.

Is there a way to correctly import my chat history or am i forever locked in the flatpack version if i want to keep them?

i'm using Linux Mint 20.3 which is based on Ubuntu 20.04 focal, both the flatpak and native versions come from the app store and are both the last official release (checked against the git repo)

Comment: Check the owner/rights first.

Comment: just checked, they were the same yet it wouldn't open it, and the new db it creates also has the same owner/rights

Comment: Just a tip: move the db to db.bak1 and db.bak to db... Restart.

Comment: also tried, as soon as it restart return the same message and generate another new db

Comment: The two instance is same version? (Maybe the db structure changed...)

Comment: I found this: https://github.com/qTox/qTox/issues/6284 ... The last answer....

Comment: read that issue, but its not the problem i'm having: i have migrated the profile and all my contacts appears without a problem, qtox native version refuses to open my user.db and keep my chat history, but it has no problem with keeping my contacts or starting new conversation with them. i just want to keep my chat history

Comment: Selinux rights maybe? ls -laZ output?

Comment: everything has [-rw-rw-r--], even the new db